# How do I implement a try again function in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

in other languages this would be doable but im not familiar in

```
echo Enter number:
read num
 { 
  function here
 }
echo your number is prime/composite
echo Try again?
```

How do I y/n here and make the whole code run again?

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: yeah its obv i have to loop it i just dont know the correct syntax actually

Comment: Time to go read the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) on loops.  You have three loops to look at, but you'll probably use a `while` loop.  You can also create functions in Bash; again, you simply need to learn how to write and use them, and that's done by reading the manual (or searching for tutorials on the web).

Comment: In the first step, I propose to write a function that checks if a passed number is prime/composite and then returns 0 or 1 depending on that.

Comment: `while :; do echo "Enter a number: "; read num; function_here num; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; printf "your number is prime/composite\ntry again?\n"; done`